# WPF DataGrid Combobox Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I tried changing `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to `DataGridTemplateColumn` without success.

The `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is working as expected but the Combobox in `DataGridTemplateColumn` is not. If I change a value in this Combobox, it will change all the **visible** Comboboxes values in all **visible** Rows.

**What I'm I missing ?**

DataGrid is like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="bookDataGrid"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bookViewSource}}">
```

The `DataGridComboboxColumn` like this:

```
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="countryColumn"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource countryLookup}}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="CountryName"
                                        SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Country,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Header="Country"
                                        Width="SizeToCells" />
```

It is used to set the Country (ID) in Books Table. I use `CollectionViewSource` for Books (bookViewSource) and Country (countryLookup).

The not working `DataGridTemplateColumn` like this:

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="CountryTemplateColumn">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="CountryCombo"                                              
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource countryLookup}}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="CountryName"
                                          SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Country, Source={StaticResource bookViewSource}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my Problem:

Add IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" to the Combobox in the DataGridTemplateColumn and remove the Source={StaticResource bookViewSource} as mm8 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Source={StaticResource bookViewSource}`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CountryCombo"                                              
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource countryLookup}}"
                DisplayMemberPath="CountryName"
                SelectedValuePath="ID"
                SelectedValue="{Binding Country, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Removed but... I get additional problems : It is changing also the Database for the visible rows. That is: If I choose a country for 1st row it will change the Country for the visible Rows in the database!

Comment: Your Book entity class is supposed to have a Country property that holds the id of the book's currently selected property. It is this property that is set when you select an item in the database.

Comment: Yes that is correct. It has a Country property which is the ID Selected from the Combobox. The strange think is that the DataGridComboboxColumn is working fine. But the Tamplatecomumn is not!

Comment: It should. Try to put the ComboBox in the <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>.

Comment: I just copy the DataGridComboBoxColumn to the tamplate column. I changed the DataGridComboBoxColumn to Combobox, I changed the SelectedValueBinding to SelectedValue. No Success same problems. If I add the Source={StaticResource bookViewSource} then the Database values are not changed, only the visual comboboxes values (7 rows). I'm Sorry if I confuse you!